# Twig finds if statement true whether or not field has value

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I have a paragraphs field that contains a sub-title which is optional. My code below still prints out the h3 tag whether or not the sub-title has any value. Any idea why this is happening as I need to hide the h3 html if there is no value, thanks.

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="bene">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>{{ content.field_title }}</h2>
            {% if content.field_sub_title %}
            <h3>{{ content.field_sub_title }}</h3>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="row">
              {{ content.field_prod }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the object itself not the render array:

```
{% if paragraph.field_sub_title %}
  <h3>{{ content.field_sub_title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: If this resolves the issue please accept.

Comment: That has not worked unfortunately

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Is this in a node template or paragraph template?

Comment: Yeah it's definitely not a cache issue as other changes in the template file are taking effect immediately. It's a paragraph template

Comment: I do this all the time. I’ll have to check my files when I’m back at a computer.

Comment: This is the first time I have noticed this, seems very odd. Will report back if I discover the reason. thanks

Comment: using  {% if paragraph.field_sub_title.0 %} has worked

Comment: Weird, I actually have this sort of thing in many places and it works for me: `{% if paragraph.field_title %}
      <h2 class="hl__comp-heading">{{ content.field_title }}</h2>
    {% endif %}`

Comment: @Kevin, using the field object is a good idea. The expression from your last comment checks if the field is defined in the paragraph type, no matter if it is empty or not. As drupalhgy commented, `.0` works because it checks for the first field item. Or you could use the negated condition `.isempty`.